# Displaying results from a fill-in choice column as URLs

Tags: list, url, choice-field

I've a list which has a choice column. Users can select one of the existing options from this column or enter one of their own. They can select as many options/enter as many options as they like (although the norm is two to three).

This produces output like so:

```
BR123457, 
CD123456, 
BR123456
```

These are all ticket identifiers which can be appended to a url to produce a page of information. I have a calculated column formula which would do this easily if there was a single entry in a text field.

However, because this is a choice column, it doesn't appear as an option for calculated column work. Does anybody have any idea how I could get these to render as URLs?

Please note, I can access Sharepoint Designer, but as I work for a large company, the overall main site I don't have access to, so I can't get too deep in code - I don't have access. So preferably any suggestions that are OOTB or using Sharepoint Designer trickery.

Answer (score 1):

Choice fields do appear for use in calculated columns - but not when they are checkboxes which allow multiple selections.

You could create a workflow which puts the values from the choice field into a hidden text field and then use that in your calculated column.

Alternatively you could use XSLT or jQuery to construct your URL.  If you have access, I usually place these type of files in the Style Library.  If not, XSL files can live in a standard document library and be referenced through the settings of a web part.  Similarly jQuery can be embedded in a HTML file, placed in a document library and referenced through a CEWP.  Both are possible with Contribute level permissions.